# Why does Dereferencing a Pointer Variable in my Helper Function causes my entire program to terminate?

Tags: c, pointers

My Helper Function, getInput() will read the data into the array list until end of input, where they will read in the Staff ID, total number of leave allowed and the number of days of leave taken so far. It is supposed to return the number of records read through the pointer variable n. However, when I try to dereference the pointer, the program will close and I am not sure why. Thank you in advance

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 80

typedef struct {
    int id; /* staff identifier */
    int totalLeave; /* the total number of days of leave allowed */
    int leaveTaken; /* the number of days of leave taken so far */
}leaveRecord;

// Function Prototypes
void getInput(leaveRecord list[ ], int *n);
int mayTakeLeave(leaveRecord list[ ], int id, int leave, int n);
void printList(leaveRecord list[ ], int n);

int main(){
    int choice, ID, LEAVE, leaveApproval;
    int recordsRead = 0;
    int *ptr = recordsRead;
    leaveRecord list[SIZE];
    do{
        printf("Please Select one of the following Options:\n");
        printf("1: getInput()\n");
        printf("2: mayTakeLeave()\n");
        printf("3: printList()\n");
        printf("4: Quit!!\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                getInput(list, recordsRead);
                printf("Temp is %d", recordsRead);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Please Enter the Staff ID:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ID);
                printf("Please Enter the Number of Days of Leave:\n");
                scanf("%d", &LEAVE);
                leaveApproval = mayTakeLeave(list,ID,LEAVE, ptr);
                switch(leaveApproval){
                    case -1:
                        printf("Error!! Staff Member not found!");
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        printf("Leave is not approved");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        printf("Leave is approved");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    }while (choice < 3);
    return 0;
}

void getInput(leaveRecord list[ ], int *n){
    int option = 0, temp = 0;
    int userInput;
    while (option == 0){
        printf("Please key in the Staff Identifier:\n");
        scanf("%d", &list->id);
        printf("Please key in the Total Number of Days allowed:\n");
        scanf("%d", &list->totalLeave);
        printf("Please key in the Number of Days of Leave taken:\n");
        scanf("%d", &list->leaveTaken);
        printf("Please Key in 1 if you like to stop adding Records:\n");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        if(userInput == 1){
            break;
        }
        temp += 1;
    }
    // Why does dereferencing a Pointer Variable kill the entire program?
    *n = temp;
}
int mayTakeLeave(leaveRecord list[ ], int id, int leave, int n){
    int leaveUsed = (leave + list->leaveTaken);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
        if(list->id == id){
            if((leaveUsed < list->totalLeave) || (leaveUsed == list->totalLeave)){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}


void printList(leaveRecord list[ ], int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
        printf(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of problems: https://pastebin.com/83QaKhB9, fixing the first one `int *ptr = recordsRead;` --> `int *ptr = &recordsRead;` will fix some of them.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I see thank you!! But why would that line be an error? I was under the impression if I had assigned like I did in my code, it will point to the address? Thank you

Comment: A pointer wants an address and `recordsRead` doesn't return an address (but a value), thats why you need to use the address of operator `&`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri ahhh I see!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getInput(leaveRecord list[ ], int *n);
```

Here, In getInput function n is an integer type pointer variable which wants address of integer variable.
But here,    `getInput(list, recordsRead)` you are just sending value of records read.

You have to send address of recordsRead.

```
getInput(list, &recordsRead)
```

Also in function printList you are using wrong syntax.
printf(list);
Do this :

```
printf("%d",list[i]);
```

or

```
printf("%d",*(list+i));
```

Comment: Ohhhh so whenever a helper function takes in a pointer as an argument, I'll have to use the address of the variable pointed to by the pointer variable as my argument? Thank you!!

Comment: I think I just did!! Im not really familiar with the site, apologies for that!!